# How to aggregate subtotals based on more than one condition?

Tags: excel

I have the following table in Excel. I would like to aggregate the goals scored and the number of games played per season per player. I tried subtotals but it does not quite give me what I want. Any ideas?

```
Season  Game_ID Team_ID Player_ID   Goals_Scored
2007-08 107141  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 
2007-08 107163  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 1
2007-08 107166  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 
2007-08 107180  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 1
2007-08 107248  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 
2007-08 107253  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 
2007-08 107261  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 
2007-08 107270  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 
2007-08 107282  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 1
2007-08 107292  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 1
2007-08 107299  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 
2007-08 107308  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 
2007-08 107310  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 
2007-08 107328  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 
2007-08 107338  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 
2008-09 108108  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 
2008-09 108115  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 
2008-09 108117  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 
2008-09 108130  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 
2008-09 108140  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 2
2008-09 108147  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 
2008-09 108151  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 
2008-09 108161  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10) 
2008-09 108166  Kispest Abass_Dieng(10)
```

Comment: Look into pivot tables:  I think that can give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a PivotTable, but given a layout as below with COUNTIFS and SUMIFS may also be possible:

[image: SO21501341 example]

where L1 has: =COUNTIFS(A:A,H1,D:D,J1)
and N1 has:  =SUMIFS(E:E,A:A,H1,D:D,J1)